# Force SignalR client connection to specific server instance

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have multiple servers running and listening to the same Hub. Unfortunately, due to how my application is built, I need that a certain set of connections to be made to the same server. I was wondering if there is any way to implement that?

The only "solution" I found, which is horrible, is to disconnect the client if one of the servers detects it shouldn't be handling that connection, causing the client to keep trying to reconnect nonstop. Unfortunately, this doesn't sound like the best approach.

I tried some other approaches, but unfortunately none of them worked at all.